# porqué este codigo funciona?

Tags: php, cookies

no entiendo como llega a entrar la primera vez al else, si de entrada seteo la cookie, alguien podría explicarmelo???

```
<?php
    setcookie('cuentaVisita',date("Y/m/d H:i:s"),time()+365*24*3600);
    if(isset($_COOKIE['cuentaVisita'])){
         $fecha = $_COOKIE['cuentaVisita'];
         $tiempo = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))-strtotime($fecha);
         echo "<br>Usted visito mi pagina hace ".$tiempo." segundos.";
    } else{
        echo "usted visita mi pagina por primera vez.";
    }
?
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. ¿Ya revisaste el Manual de PHP: *[Si existe algún tipo de output anterior a la llamada de esta función, setcookie() fallará y retornará FALSE. Si setcookie() ejecuta satisfactoriamente, retornará TRUE. Esto no indica si es que el usuario ha aceptado la cookie o no.](http://php.net/manual/es/function.setcookie.php)*  ? ¿Puedes garantizar lo que ahí se afirma? Puedes probar el resultado haciendo: `$mCookie=setcookie('cuentaVisita',date("Y/m/d H:i:s"),time()+365*24*3600);` y luego: `var_dump($mCookie);`

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Pon un print_r($_COOKIE) delante de la linea del if y mira ver que llega